# How can I import Sage functions into a web-based application or into python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, math, 2d-games, sage

I am a beginner programmer, so bear with me. :)

I am trying to create a game that uses certain graph theory and group theory functions from Sage. I would like to share this game with other people, and possibly make it into a web-based game.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to integrate Sage script into a web based application?
- If not, is it possible to import sage functions into Python 3?
- Do you have any other suggestions on how I can use mathematical programming in a web-based environment?

I know that it is possible to import sage functions into Python 2, but I could not find a way to do this in Python 3.

Comment: Most functions in Sage come from other packages that are "linked into" Sage, which unites and acts as a front end to those packages. Have you tried finding which packages have those functions and use Python 3 versions of those packages?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find any sources on this.